# Unable to create audit trail file

Tags: oracle, audit-trail

We are running Oracle 11g R2.  We are creating a new database.  On the first attempt to start in nomount mode, we had forgotten to create the Audit Trail Dest.  So, we created that directroy.

Now, the directory exists, we can write to it, we've tried 755 + 777, but we cannot even get into SQLPlus.

```
ERROR:
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 9925
ORA-01075: you are currently logged on
```

Is there some hidden file or something that is left over from the first attempt?  We're into 3 hours and still no luck........

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it was semaphores. Needed to shut down all other instances and see what was left, and remove them.